# Necessary and sufficient condition for an Euler circuit

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have come across the theorem ***A connected multigraph with at least two vertices has an Euler
circuit if and only if each of its vertices has even degree***. I just want to know whether the same holds for connected simple graphs as well. Thanks

Comment: hint: every simple graph is a valid multigraph

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks for the hint

Comment: Hint: the previous hint should be sufficient to answer your question completely.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes I meant thanks for the "answer" :)